# Workflowmax client update endpoint giving 500 error

Tags: xero-api

When I try to update the existing client with https://api.xero.com/workflowmax/3.0/client.api/update this endpoint, I am getting a 500 error without any details.client list and get endpoints working fine. I tried with one field update. That also failing. any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please can you raise a case with Xero (api@xero.com) and include the client id for your app, the tenant name, the time and date of the most recent error and the payload that you were sending.